# Efficient grouping by key and StatCounter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am aggregating values by parameter as below using apache-spark and scala. 
This keeps adding values to "List" 
Is there more efficient way to get list by key and StatCounter?

```
val predictorRawKey = predictorRaw.map { x =>
      val param = x._1
      val val: Double = x._2.toDouble
      (param, val)
    }.mapValues(num => List( num) )
     .reduceByKey((l1, l2) => l1 ::: l2)
     .map { x => x._1, StatCounter(x._2.iterator))
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters you shouldn't use `reduceByKey` to group values. It is more efficient to omit map side aggregation and use `groupByKey` directly.

Fortunately `StatCounter` can work in a streaming fashion and there is no need to group values at all:

```
import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter

val pairs = predictorRawKey.map(x => (x._1, x._2.toDouble))

val predictorRawKey = pairs.aggregateByKey(StatCounter(Nil))(
  (acc: StatCounter, x: Double) => acc.merge(x),
  (acc1: StatCounter, acc2: StatCounter) => acc1.merge(acc2)
)
```

Comment: Oh I really appreciate it!

Comment: I thought reduceByKey already has  operation like (acc, x) => acc.merge(x)  internally. Can you please briefly explain  difference(s) between reduceByKey and aggregateByKey. Generally, we can say aggregateByKey is more efficient (well, I would say "efficient" if it's stable and fast) Thanks!

Comment: It is all about types. `pairs` is `RDD[(T, Double)]` and `predictorRawKey` is `RDD[(T, StatCounter)]`. Since types don't match you cannot use `reduceByKey`. You could `map` `pairs` to `RDD[(T, StatCounter)]` and `reduceByKey` but there is no reason to create a large number of temporary objects.